# Load large csv's directly into Big Query without cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking into loading CSV(s) into Big Query from a remote server, and they will be greater than 10MB, even if compressed. My understanding is that to load remote files directly into Big Query, this would technically follow the process of "load data from local files" implemented in a script on the remote server where the data lives.

According to big query documentation, this is limited to 10MB/File. Do I need to load files into GCS and then use BQ Data Transfer Service for this task? Is breaking down huge CSV's into a bunch of 10MB CSV's a practical option? This needs to be scalable.

Comment: The 10 MB limitation applies to loading files using the Google Cloud Console GUI. Instead, use the CLI `bq load` instead of trying to split files.

Answer (score 4):

The right way is to upload the file in Cloud Storage and then to perform a [load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) from GCS (not a Transfer Service).

The load job is powerful. It's very fast, and you can import one a several file in the same time and in the same table!

It's definitively the best way to be scalable.